# Multiple objective functions with binary variables Google OR-tools

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I have a set of *U users* and a set of *S servers*. I want to maximize the number of users allocated to a server while minimizing the number of servers used (this means that I have two objective functions).

Each user has some requirements *w* and each server has a total capacity of *C*.

**The solver variables are the following:**

```
# x[i,j] = True if user u[j] is allocated to server s[i]
# x[i,j] = False otherwise

# y[i] = True if server s[i] is used to serve users
# y[i] = False otherwise
```

As mentioned before, I want to maximize *x[i,j]* while minimizing *y[i]*

**The constraints are the following:**

- Capacity constraint: Since each server *i* has a certain capacity, the allocation of *j* users must not exceed that capacity
- Proximity constraint: Only users located within the range of the server can be allocated to it. A user can be located in the overlapping range of multiple servers
- Constraint family: Ensures every user is allocated to at most one server.

Using this library

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
```

So far I've done:

- Create the solver variables (they are boolean)
- Create the constraints
- Maximize the x[i,j] variable
- Obtain the objective function

For instance, if I have 10 users and 4 servers all the 10 users are allocated among the 4 servers

What I need but haven't been able to accomplish:

- Maximize the `x[i,j]` variable AND Minimize the `y[i]` variable

For the same 10 users and the same 4 servers above, all the 10 users can be allocated among just 2 servers and not 4

I have tried the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515182/are-multiple-objectives-possible-or-tools-constraint-programming) post but it is not working since I got that the problem does not have an optimal solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are usually 2 approaches:

- weighted sum: a * obj1 + b * obj2
- lexicographic: optimize obj1, get optimal value, change objective to obj2, add constraint obj1 <= best_obj1_value (optional + slack). Then reoptimize. Bonus point when reusing the optimal solution with obj1 as a hint for the second solve.

Comment: On that first approach, what are the weights equivalent to?

Comment: Relative weights of each objective. If a > b, then obj1 will be favored. ...