# How do multiple model.Minimize work during single solve?

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

Assuming I have a program with multiple Minimizes applied to three different cp-sat model objectives. How will they work? Will there be any priority between the three objectives? Will order of those objectives affect the result or the solving process?

Research shows some sources with suggestions to apply Minimizes iteratively. For example: [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74444165/multiple-objective-functions-with-binary-variables-google-or-tools) and [this Kripke tutorial](https://github.com/d-krupke/cpsat-primer#objectives).

Official documentation didn't mention any specifics [HERE](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/sat/python/cp_model#minimize). And I didn't find any hints in the source code on the same page.

I made a python script to test whether multiple Minimizes will work at all and whether they'll provide a reasonable answer. I also limited amount of solutions to 10 with a simple custom callback. At a first glance it looks like those Minimizes do affect the result and probably with same priorities.

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


class CallbackStopper(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):

    def __init__(self):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.solutions = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.solutions += 1
        if self.solutions == 10:
            self.StopSearch()


def solve_multiple_minimizes(minimizes = 0):
    model = cp_model.CpModel()
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

    data = [model.NewIntVar(0, 100, f'<num_{i}>') for i in range(20)]
    model.AddAllDifferent(data)

    if minimizes >= 1:
        every_second_one = [n for i, n in enumerate(data) if i % 2]
        for i in range(1, len(every_second_one)):
            model.Add(every_second_one[i-1] < every_second_one[i])
        model.Minimize(sum(every_second_one))

    if minimizes >= 2:
        quorter = data[len(data)//4:]
        model.Minimize(sum(quorter))

    if minimizes >= 3:
        half = data[len(data)//2:]
        model.Minimize(sum(half))

    status = solver.Solve(model, CallbackStopper())

    if status not in (cp_model.OPTIMAL, cp_model.FEASIBLE):
        print(f'{solver.ResponseProto()}')
        return '- error -'
    
    return [solver.Value(n) for n in data]

for i in range(4):
    print(f'{i = }: {solve_multiple_minimizes(i)}')
'''
Printed output

i = 0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
i = 1: [10, 0, 11, 1, 13, 2, 15, 3, 17, 4, 19, 5, 12, 6, 14, 7, 16, 8, 18, 9]
i = 2: [19, 3, 18, 4, 17, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0, 8, 9, 10, 15, 12, 11, 13, 16, 14]
i = 3: [15, 4, 16, 5, 18, 6, 19, 7, 17, 9, 2, 10, 8, 11, 0, 12, 3, 13, 1, 14]
'''
```

Comment: If you call minimize multiple times on the same model (which you are not doing in your code, but suggest otherwise in your title), each new minimize overwrite the previous one.

Comment: Thanks. Please help me understand how am I not applying multiple minimizes? When the bottom loop reaches i == 3, all of ifs inside the function apply their minimizes to the model object. What am I missing?